# Clean way to overload/override/hide method on derived classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have 1 Base Class `A` and 4 derived classes `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`.

and there's a method `func(arg1: string)` in class `A` that do `X`.

class `B` override `func(arg1: string)` and do `X` but insert code in the middle of `X` to do `B exclusive`.

class `C` has additional argument `func(arg1: string, arg2: number)` and do similar like class `B`.

class `D` has different arguments `func(arg1: boolean, arg2: boolean)` and do similar like class `B`.

class `E` override `func(arg1: string)` normally

basically, I want to achieve something like this

```
class A {
 protected func(arg1: string) {
    // do X
 }
}

class B extends A {
  protected func(arg1: string) {
    // do X halfway
    // do something exclusive for B
    // do the rest of X
  }
}

class C extends A {
  protected func(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
    // do X halfway
    // do something exclusive for C
    // do the rest of X
  }
}

class D extends A {
  protected func(arg1: boolean, arg2: boolean) {
    // do X halfway
    // do something exclusive for D
    // do the rest of X
  }
}

class E extends A {
  protected func(arg1: string) {
    // do something exclusive for E
    super.func();
  }
}
```

additionally, make class `C` and `D` can't access `func(arg1: string)`

```
objectB.func('foobar'); // will do func on class B
objectC.func('foobar'); // forbid doing this
objectD.func('foobar'); // forbid doing this
objectE.func('foobar'); // will do func on class E
```

and lastly, let's say that `do something exclusive for B, C, D, and E` only has 1 line of code, while `X` has quite a lot of line of codes.

How to achieve that while implement clean code ?

should I just remove `func` on class `A` and write `func` on each derived classes that do `X` and do something exclusive for respective class? (the simplest way that i can think of, but i dont know whether it's clean or not)

or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to do this and one way to *not* do this.

#### #1 - Composition, not inheritance

Instead of providing a protected method `doFoo` you instead provide a `fooer`:

```js
// Change this type to take arguments and return values
// if `fooer` needs to behave differently on the basis of `specialLogic`
type VoidFunc = (() => void)
const fooer = (arg: string, specialLogic: VoidFunc = () => {}) => {
  // Some of X
  specialLogic()
  // The rest of X
}
```

Then you provide a `fooer` to those classes that need a fooer and they can do as they will:

```js
// Just one example
class C {
  constructor(private fooer: Fooer) {}
  protected func(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
    this.fooer(arg1 + "stuff", () => console.log("Doing special logic for C"))
  }
}
```

#### #2 `private` body, `protected` hooks

The more classically OOP approach (but which scales much more poorly in my opinion) is to add `protected` hook methods and have the body of the private orchestrating method call the hooks at the appropriate time:

```js
class A {
  public /* or protected */ methodUsingFunc() {
    // other stuff
    this.func("hello world!");
  }
  private reallyDoFunc(arg: string) {
    beforeFunc();
    // Some of X
    duringFunc();
    // More of X
    afterFunc();
  }
  protected beforeFunc() { }
  protected duringFunc() { }
  protected afterFunc() { }
}
```

Then your sub-classes override the hooks they care about:

```js
class C extends A {
  protected duringFunc() { console.log("Hello from C!"); }
}

new C().methodUsingFunc();
```

This presumes that you can hide `func(string)`.

#### #3 Don't do this

Sometimes `X` just *looks* similar, but is only similar in what you *type* not what you want it to do.  Trying to shoehorn three separate concepts into one abstraction never works, no matter how much they all look like each other (remember, under the hood *all* computation is just `doMutableBooleanLogic` but we don't just write that one method for *everything* we do).  In which case, factoring out things that are *really* shared and using pattern #1 for bits of logic which *must* all change together and *copy-pasting* the bits that look-the-same-but-are-not-actually will be **much** better for maintainability in the long term.

See also Sandi Metz's [*The Wrong Abstraction*](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction)

Comment: Thank you! it looks like pattern #2 more readable. and since `X` doing same thing except in the middle of it, then i can just create 1  protected method instead of 3, to do special things for each derived classes